# MVVM, изменение Visibility через команду из диалогового окна

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь реализовать паттерн MVVM. Во View имеется TabControl со следующим TabItem:

```
<TabItem Background="{x:Null}" Name="diagram" 
         Visibility="{Binding Path=DiagramTabVisibility,
             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Свойство Visibility привязано к свойству DiagramTabVisibility во ViewModel:

```
bool _diagramTabVisibility = false;
public bool DiagramTabVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return _diagramTabVisibility;
    }
    set
    {
        _diagramTabVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DiagramTabVisibility");
    }
}
```

Изменение вышеуказанного свойство реализовано через команду:

```
RelayCommand _diagramTabItem;
public ICommand DiagramTabItem
{
    get
    {
        if (_diagramTabItem == null)
            _diagramTabItem =
                new RelayCommand(
                        ExecuteDiagramTabItemCommand,
                        CanExecuteDiagramTabItemCommand);
        return _diagramTabItem;
    }
}

public void ExecuteDiagramTabItemCommand(object Parameter)
{
    DiagramTabVisibility = !DiagramTabVisibility;
}

public bool CanExecuteDiagramTabItemCommand(object Parameter)
{
    return true;
}
```

При вызове команды из View никаких проблем не возникает, свойство Visibility изменяется и указанный элемент сворачивается/разворачивается.
Однако у меня стоит задача изменения видимости из диалогового окна, в котором имеется точно такая же кнопка, которая работает во View:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DiagramTabItem}">Диаграмма</Button>
```

Диалоговое окно вызываю через команду со следующим кодом:

```
WindowAddDiagram newWindow = new WindowAddDiagram();
newWindow.Owner = this;
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Я подозреваю, что по какой-то причине при исполнении команды из другого окна не срабатывает `OnPropertyChanged("DiagramTabVisibility"). При этом, если поставить точку останова на свойстве DiagramTabVisibility, то видно, что значение меняется, но на View почему-то никаких изменений нет.

**Дополнено:**
Datacontext привязывается в XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:RegAPI />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Где RegAPI - ViewModel. Datacontext и главного и диалогового окна - RegAPI.

Comment: А к чему байндиться ваша кнопка в диалоговом окне? Судя по тому, что в коде вы DataContext не устанавливаете, значит делаете это в XAML, а это значит, что у основного и диалогового окна ViewModel разные. Если свойство и изменяется, то только не в основном окне, потому ничего и не происходит. Вам нужно наладить взаимодействие между окнами.

Comment: Напишите как вы устанавливаете `DataContext`

Comment: <Window.DataContext>
        <local:RegAPI></local:RegAPI>
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: дело в том, что команда находится в RegAPI, которое является ViewModel основного окна. Просто она запускается из диалогового окна....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете новый экземпляр `RegAPI`, естественно, что изменения в нем не действуют на другие экземпляры.

Задавайте в качестве `DataContext` *тот же* экземпляр, например так:

```
WindowAddDiagram newWindow = new WindowAddDiagram();
newWindow.Owner = this;
newWindow.DataContext = DataContext;
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```